# Do foreign keys gets inserted when primary key is inserted?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design

A very basic question I'm confused about, similar to UPDATE and DELETE CASCADE, do foreign keys gets inserted automatically when a referenced table's primary key is inserted?

Or are they simply a constraint that tells to check the primray key that is being reference and if present add, else error.

As a example, I'm asking about something like this:

```
...
CONSTRAINT    idFK
   FOREIGN KEY(id)
   REFERENCES Users(id)
   ON DELETE CASCADE
   ON UPDATE CASCADE
...
```

Here, will `id` in this table automatically get inserted when an id is inserted in `Users` table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you insert a record in "Users" table , nothing inserted in any other tables.
when you insert a record in a table with foreign key, the value of foreign key field just will check with the primary key value in parent(Here "Users") table.